# How to reduce output voltage ripple in a buck converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ltspice, buck

This is a buck converter.  It has some rippleon the output voltage.

[image]

[image]

How can I reduce the ripple?

Comment: The amplitude of these "ripples" is `0.005V`. I'd say there is nothing to reduce.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What do you want to power and how low ripple do you want?

Comment: Actually, I just want to see, how can we reduce even that less ripple.

Comment: MOAR filtering! Or increase the frequency of operation. Beware, some IC regulators require a minimum ripple on the first capacitor as part of their control feedback, in which case you'd need to add another stage of filtering to reduce the ripple delivered to the load.

Comment: 13 mV p-p ripple is pretty good for a switcher. Why do you need to reduce it? Run at 100 kHz.

Comment: You have since long passed the point of deminishing returns when it comes to filtering. Next step would be a linear regulator.

Comment: @Neil_UK is adding more filtering that simple? I thought that the problem was keeping the feedback control loop stable. Would adding more filters require redesigning the control circuitry?

Comment: @DanielFarrell Read my comment in full. The stability-controlling feedback for the regulator is taken from the earliest stages. The voltage controlling feedback operates slower and could be taken from the same place, or from the filter output.

Answer (score 1):

That, 5mV, is a valid concern for analog or high resolution mixed signal circuitry. I put LDO(s) after a switched mode converter.